# No Internet Access for a given machine, others work fine

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have an older laptop (Windows 8.1, latest patches installed) which has not been used for some time, upon reconnecting it I have a very strange problem with internet access via WiFi:

- the WiFi indicator says "Limited"
- I do not have Internet access
- I can ping the router and other machines on the same network
- these machines have access to Internet (via the same WiFi AP)
- when doing a `tracert` to 8.8.8.8 (or others) I just go though the first hop (my Internet box) and then "cannot reach requested network"
- the other machines on my network can do the same traceroute successfully
- my box sees the laptop the same way than the other devices
- I rebooted everything (including the Internet box), requested a new DHCP IP (by deleting the static DHCP assignment I had before)
- I re-installed the driver of the card, also tried the previous version
- when connected to another WiFi AP the laptop connects to Internet fine

It looks like my router (the Internet box) refuses to forward packets specifically from that machine. Since troubleshooting that will be way more complicated (this is an ADSL box from my Internet provider - Freebox in France if this can help) I would like to check if someone did not have a similar weird issue?

Comment: What happens if you look up the current IP address given by the dhcp server, then manually set the ip address to a different one? Could be that an ip address is somehow blocked in a router somewhere. also try setting this ip to another machine and see if that one still has access.

Comment: I tried that, using two different addresses. The "network unreachable" info from tracert happens right after the box hop, thus my suspicion about dropping some specific packets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the network from `n` to `g` and the problem is gone. It looks like (I am speculating) there is a very specific issue with how packets are crafted by the driver in this mode, then being rejected by the outgress router.

I will file a bug with the vendor of the laptop.